# Javascript input value in a textarea in an h2 element

Tags: javascript, html, opencart

So this is my question.

I have this code down here,it works,and does what it is supposed to do

Get value from an input field log it in the console to check what it got and posts it into the textarea.

```
<input id="pname" value="We have some text here">

<input type="button" value="Generate" onclick="Go();">
<textarea id="dname"></textarea>

<script>
function Go () {
    var Pname = document.getElementById("pname").value;
    console.log(Pname);
    var dname = document.getElementById("dname").innerHTML = Pname;

}
</script>
```

So here is the issues that i am running into ,hence i am doing this on the opencart platform and the textarea that i am targeting is using a ckeditor editor,i get an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Can someone point out why it's working on a normal textarea but not on the other one?

Comment: Can you confirm using Dev Tools if selected element is rendered as an `textarea`

Comment: Hmm,it's actually using an html page with a body but still,i tried to use my code to access an h2 tag which i made,still could not access it.But still my code targets an ID element which is within that textarea (outside of it works fine)